# Spring-Data: Define <mongo:options> using java based config

Tags: java, configuration, spring-data-mongodb

When we configure Spring-Data for `mongo-db` we have options for configure using `Java based` and `XML based`. In XML based configurations, we also customize mango options using `<mongo:options connections-per-host="4" ...` tag, But in java based configuration, how i set these options for `Mongo` Configuration?.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions'

```
MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                                 .connectionsPerHost( 4 ).build();

ServerAddress severAddress = new ServerAddress( mongoDbAddress );

return new MongoClient( severAddress, options );
```